# How to calculate true matches in feature matching?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection, flann

I am doing feature matching in OpenCV Python using two images of the same model taken from different viewpoints. The feature matching algorithms I have used till now are FLANN and Brute Force. I have already done feature detection with Harris, Shi-Tomasi, ORB, MSER, etc. The descriptor I am using are ORB and BRISK. After I get the output of feature matching, how do I calculate the true matches and false matches? For me, it is not possible to do it manually as I have limited time and the lines drawn as matches are not very clear. Is there any way to calculate true matches and false matches easily?

Please also note that I am a beginner in this field and I don't really know any complex mathematical functions.

Any help will be kindly appreciated.

Comment: if your scene is planar, a good way to get inliers and outliers of the matching is to compute the best homography between both images and discard all matches where the homography-transformed point differs too much (typically > 2-3 pixels) from the matched point. If you want to give the manual way a try, dont try to evaluate the whole matching at once, but only show and accept/reject one match at a time.

Comment: one way to reject a lot of false matches is to test the 2 best matches for each point and if their descriptor distance is ambiguous, reject them.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there any any available link for the techniques that you mentioned in Opencv Python?

Comment: cv2.findHomography computes inliers/outliers for you with the `mask` output array. https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html

Comment: Additionally, if you have a larger number of features you can use `cv.findFundamentalMat` with different methods for outlier removal (e.g. RANSAC) and also save the output in a `mask`.

Comment: Do you have perhaps have the link to that code? I do have a large number of features and my scene is planar.

Comment: Hope it helps: https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gae420abc34eaa03d0c6a67359609d8429